# We get following error message in logs any idea how to fix it?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, sql

> a:5:{i:0;s:1058:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in 'where clause', query was: `` SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3' INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1)) WHERE (`e`.`type_id` != 'amgiftcard') AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1) + 1 ORDER BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 1) + 1 ASC ``";i:1;s:5839:"#0 includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall the *amgiftcard* module. As I can see in the query it is not the base column. In my database your query throws the same error:

[image: same error]

But without the line `` (`e`.`type_id` != 'amgiftcard') AND `` the query works fine:

[image: query works fune]

#### EDIT:

There is no `type_id` column (by default) inside the `catalog_product_index_price` table:

[image: catalog_product_index_price table]

#### EDIT 2:

I think an error is somewhere in an observer of the `amgiftcard` module. Try to contact [their support team](https://amasty.com/contacts/).

Comment: Okay, i might try this, ill respond as soon ill contacted their support+

Comment: sorry :), done!